# Is there a way to play minecraft with the same accounts without a server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I had gotten Minecraft about a  year ago and I paid for an account. We have another computer so my brother plays on it with my account. Now we both can play on it at the same time. Is there a way for us both to play together without an actual server you have to pay for?

Comment: but Non-Master Race I don't own a server and i can't get one.

Comment: You can set up a server on your own PC. I don't believe the minecraft server software costs anything.

Comment: @TrentHawkins you are correct, software doesn't cost anything.

Comment: Um, can you not open it to LAN and play?

Answer (score 2):

When you startup Minecraft, login with the wrong password.  It will give you an error and a button will pop up that says `Play Offline`.  Click on that, and Minecraft will launch.  The one of you that logged in with your account should start a LAN world (press `esc` on the keyboard in-game and click `Open to LAN`), and the other one should be able to join the game by clicking on `Multiplayer` and then join the LAN world that pops up at the bottom of the screen.  The person who clicked on `Play Offline`'s name tag in game will be `Player`.